# How to read ASCII characters from a file in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

My file contains ASCII characters in bytes. I want to read ASCII characters like 'ABCD'(four bytes) from that file. Could you please help me how to do this in Dart.?

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty much the default, although if you have a byte with the most-significant bit as a 1, it's no longer an ASCII file.

Comment: Could you please tell me what's the default way you mentioned.? Did you say about implementing through  AsciiCodec class in Dart.?

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files

Comment: Let me go through that, Thank you.!